# What do the underscores mean in DOM object detail view? (Firebug)

Tags: javascript, firebug

Three (out of 8 or so) of the parameters in an object have an underscore at the beginning of their name. The underscores aren't in my json object and I can't decipher why Firebug would add them in. The same properties are listed later in the object but without the underscores. I'm sure it's trivial but I'm curious to know.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: firebug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug does not add underscores to variables.  These underscores are already there.

Answer (score 1):

Prefixing a variable/property name with an underscore is simply a JavaScript coding convention. It usually implies that those variables are "private," or at least not meant for use by "outsiders."

---

There are a number of other languages which actually *use* underscore prefixes. For instance, two preceding underscores (`__`) makes a member private in Python; in C++, a single leading underscore is reserved in global namespaces ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)).

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783858/underscores-in-function-names).