# Double underscore in front of a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code snippet in my node code.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(__dirname, function (err, files) {
    console.log(files);
});
```

Why does the variable '__dirname' have double underscores?
I know that one underscore is a naming convention for a private/protected variable... but does double underscore mean something more?

Comment: It's just a naming convention..

Comment: No, it has no other meaning than a naming convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`__dirname`** and **`__filename`** are local to each module but with the particularity that are strings.

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html

documentation specifies:

```
__dirname isn't actually a global but rather local to each module.
```

and normally underscore means private ( [In Javascript, what does this underscore mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288756/in-javascript-what-does-this-underscore-mean/8288762#8288762) )

It can be interpreted as a local private variable to the module.