# React Native: Hooks - useRef

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I have been working on ReactJS but totally new to React Native. I am trying to use `useRef` on TextInput but it did not work.

```
const Playground = () =>{

  const inputName = useRef();

  const addName = e => {
    Alert.alert(inputName.current.value);  
  }

  return (
      <SafeAreaView>    
            <TextInput ref={inputName} placeholder="name"></TextInput>
            <Button title="add" onPress={addName}></Button>          
      </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default Playground;
```

With the code I use in ReactJS above, it always returns me empty string when pressing the button to `addName`. I also tried to `useEffect` as below but got the same results.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!inputName.current) return;

    Alert.alert(inputName.current.value);

  }, [inputName.current])
```

Tried to do some search but I could not find the answer. Can I use `useRef` in React Native as the same as ReactJS?

Comment: I think your problem is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324660/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-textinput-in-an-onpress-handler. I suggest you control your value via state instead of getting it from the ref, but if you prefer there is this _lastNativeText property you can use.

Comment: Thanks gIneto. I am more curious to know if I should not use `useRef` in react native.

Comment: We have `useRef` in production with `react-native`, it works as expected for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
inputName.current._root.props.value
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe React Native strongly encourages using state instead of ref. You can get away with `useState` in this particular case.

See also [Direct Manipulation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation)