# how to change worldCopyJump value dynamically in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Initialized leaflet map with worldCopyJump as true

```js
var map = L.map('weatherMap', {
  center: [51.505, -0.09],
  zoom: 13,
  worldCopyJump: true
});
```

need to change worldCopyJump as false after that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [Leaflet's source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/tree/master/src), you can see that the `worldCopyJump` map option is evaluated only once, when the [map drag handler is being enabled](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/b7cbcb39b85dfbf9e8227339fd92f298bbc3151e/src/map/handler/Map.Drag.js#L70) for the first time (notice how `this._draggable` is cached and never destroyed).

You can access the map handlers as [map properties](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#map-property), then [enable and disable them](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#handler). As the `worldCopyJump` option is evaluated when enabling the dragging handler for the first time (when its internal `_draggable` property is falsy), one is able to do something like:

```
map.dragging.disable();
delete map.dragging._draggable;
map.options.worldCopyJump = !map.options.worldCopyJump;
map.dragging.enable();
```

Remember the javascript unwritten convention that [properties and methods starting with an underscore (`_`) are meant to be protected/private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288756/in-javascript-what-does-this-underscore-mean) - deleting `_draggable` above is quite an ugly hack.

Ideally, the code for the draggable handler for `L.Map` could be refactored in order to evaluate the `worldCopyJump` option on re-enabling the dragging handler. However, the use cases for this are very niche and nobody has undertaken that (as of this writing).