# How to get the value of TextInput in React Native without using state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know I can do this using `this.state` but I want to make my code uniform. I have both web app and mobile app connected via an API.

This is what my ReactJS Web App looks like **(this one works)**:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class SignIn extends React.Component {
  signIn = () => {
    var username = this.refs.username.value;
    var password = this.refs.password.value;

    console.log(username); //works
    console.log(password); //works
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref='username' placeholder='Username' />
        <input ref='password' type='password' placeholder='Password' />
        <button onClick={this.signIn.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The above code does not use any states to get the values of the textboxes and I want to achieve the same thing in React Native.

In my mobile app I have the following code **(this doesn't work)**:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Alert, TextInput, View, Button} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  signIn = () => {
    var username = this.refs.username.value;
    var password = this.refs.password.value;

    Alert.alert(username); //doesn't work
    Alert.alert(password); //doesn't work
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 60}}>
        <TextInput ref='username' placeholder='Username' autoCapitalize='none' />
        <TextInput ref='password' placeholder='Password' autoCapitalize='none' secureTextEntry={true} />
        <Button title='Submit' onPress={this.signIn.bind(this)} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I want the code to be uniform as possible but the same logic does not work in React Native. Is it possible to do this without using state?

Comment: I am not sure which version of react you use in your Native app but probably instead of string refs, you can try callback refs, `<TextInput ref={(ref) = this.username=ref} placeholder='Username' autoCapitalize='none' />` and use it like `this.username`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I'm getting `Reference Error: Can't find variable: ref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.refs.username._lastNativeText` to get the inner text value of the `username` field.

However, going forward, this is not the best way to do it according to official RN guide. Refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52693820/keep-getting-an-error-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-refs-name-v/52698306#52698306) for more details.

Comment: Your answer `this.refs.username.input._lastNativeText` gives me an error while `this.refs.username._lastNativeText` works perfectly.

Comment: Oh, all right. I didn't verify it in IDE before posting. I have updated the answer.

Comment: NOTE: This method stops working on React Native 0.62. `_lastNativeText` is undefined in this version.

Comment: I used this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53878044/9375533