# javascript oop with fixed this scope?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement some basic object orientation in javascript like so:

```
function Cat(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Cat.prototype.sayName = function() {
  console.log(this.name);
};

Cat.prototype.fetchCat = function() {
  someAsyncCall()
      .success(this.sayName)
      .error(someOtherMethod);
};
```

when `someAsyncCall` is finished `sayName` gets called but the `this` scope is not what I expect. I can solve it by binding:

```
Cat.prototype.fetchCat = function() {
  someAsyncCall()
      .success(this.sayName.bind(this))
      .error(someOtherMethod.bind(this));
};
```

Is there some syntactically "nicer" solution to this than having to remember to `.bind` all the time when in callbacks?

Comment: Maybe not the best solution, but I usually use a local variable `var self = this;` in the function so that `self` can be used in the callbacks to be sure the correct `this` is being used.

Answer (score 1):

```
Cat.prototype.fetchCat = function() {
var self = this;
  someAsyncCall()
      .success(function(){self.sayName})
      .error(someOtherMethod);
};
```

Comment: I think you need `.success(function(){self.sayName();})` or it'll be the same as passing this.sayname

Comment: Actually both will be working, **but** using mine assume we are using `self` everywhere in the other functions instead of `this`, yours will  allow using `this` in the right context which is actually better. I updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

With reference to [javascript guide lines from airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript),

```
// bad
function() {
  var self = this;
  return function() {
    console.log(self);
  };
}

// bad
function() {
  var that = this;
  return function() {
    console.log(that);
  };
}

// good
function() {
  var _this = this;
  return function() {
    console.log(_this);
  };
}
```

[ecma-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6) does not give any special treatment for underscore and says:

> The dollar sign ($) and the underscore (_) are permitted anywhere in
>   an IdentifierName.

but since javascript as a language does not support encapsulation out of the box, the '_' convention is meant to indicate that the variable is 'private' or shouldn't be used externally.

Comment: Possible reason here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484424/underscore-prefix-for-property-and-method-names-in-javascript), still I strongly prefer "self"