# Javascript - Need an Underscore in Function Name?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't have any trouble with this code but I am very curious as to why the function below seems to need an underscore in its name.

```
function _clear()
    {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML =  "";
    }
```

The function _clear() only executes after clicking the button if the function name contains an underscore.

```
<button type="submit" onClick="_clear()">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underscore prefix for property and method names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484424/underscore-prefix-for-property-and-method-names-in-javascript)

Comment: I think `clear` is a built-in function. Thus, your browser tries to call the base function, not the one you have previously defined.

Comment: can you provide a working model

Comment: Not a duplicate in the slightest with reference to the resource alluded to by @Chris, a discussion which focuses on a naming convention related to encapsulating data in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear), clear() is a method of the Document object, which one might call by writing `document.clear()`. But, since this method is deprecated one ought not to call it at all.  In fact, in HTML5, the method does nothing (see [HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#dom-document-clear)).

So, until this method is actually removed from the Document object, one might conclude that a *potential* conflict exists in having a user-defined function with the same name as that of the Document's method. That said, the following code runs just fine using Google Chrome (Version 49.0.2623.112 m):

```
var d = document;
d.g = d.getElementById;

function clear()
{
        d.g("test").innerHTML =  "";
    }

var test = d.g("test");
test.onmouseover=clear;
```

See [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bREqJP)

It's unlikely that there is a conflict between clear() and document.clear().  I wrote a user-defined function that uses the same name as another document method and the code ran flawlessly; see [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjZmvZ?editors=1111).

Apparently, when the onclick event attribute is given the user-defined function "clear()" there is some kind of confusion with clear() being associated with `document.clear()`; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript) and read the excellent explanation in the official answer. In brief, the issue boils down to "...the Document object is in the scope chain before the Window object (...)" (see [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://books.google.com/books?id=2weL0iAfrEMC&lpg=PT420&ots=_9WAnxW1aD&dq=inline%20event%20handlers%20scope%20chain%20document&pg=PT420#v=onepage&q=Document%20object%20is%20in%20the%20scope&f=false)).

If for some reason you were determined for the code to work, here's how to specify the correct context:

HTML:

```
<div id="test">a test to see if this will clear</div>
<button id="but" onclick="window.clear()">Clear</button>
```

So, the user-defined function actually becomes a method of the Window object, along side the built-in ones like window.open(), allowing the code to execute; see [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXeGvm?editors=1011).

Note, the best way to have an action occur when a click event occurs is to put this line in your JavaScript code given a button with an id of "but":

```
but.addEventListener('click',clear);
```

See [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZjvGv?editors=1011).

Answer (score 1):

That's because `clear()` is a function that already exists in JavaScript. You could also add the underscore to the end or add another c or do anything so that the function has a different name.