# What is the underscore "_" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm doing a redux tutorial, and I saw a call like this:

```
this._render();
```

and it's defined elsewhere as:

```
_render() {
    ....
}
```

What is the underscore "_"? Why is it used?

Comment: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-underscore-dangle

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is convention of private methods and variables. In JavaScript there is no real privacy of classes.

It means that you should not use these method (starting with "`_`") out of your object. Of course technically you can, but "`_`" means that you should not.

Answer (score 14):

Underscore (`_`) is just a plain valid character for variable/function name, it does not bring any additional feature.

However, it is a good convention to use underscore to mark variable/function as private. You can check [Underscore prefix for property and method names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484424/underscore-prefix-for-property-and-method-names-in-javascript) for some previous discussion.

Answer (score 3):

The underscore is simply a valid character in an identifier, so the method's name is `_render`.

It's a common pattern in languages without access modifiers to use underscores to denote private methods. In a language such as C#, which does have access modifiers, I could define a method as:

```
private void Foo() {}
```

The method `Foo` can then only be called from within the class which defined it.

In JavaScript you can't do this, so it's a typical design pattern to prefix the method with `_` to show that it should be treated as private.

```
this._foo();
```

You can still call this method, it's just not considered good practice to do it outside of the class definition.