# What does the underscore do in the following code?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am working on a React frontend with a delete method which deletes an item in the database.
Having a hard time with the following code.

```
deleteFromDB = idTodelete => {
    let objIdToDelete = null;
    this.state.data.forEach(dat => {
      if (dat.id == idTodelete) {
        objIdToDelete = dat._id;
      }
    });
```

This is the method called after entering the ID to be deleted and this modifies the state by deleting the item corresponding to the ID

Comment: This could be a typo, but maybe the objects in your state have two `ID` attributes. `id` might be a 'frontend' ID whereas `_id` is the ID used in the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the underscore "\_" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734399/what-is-the-underscore-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible that _id is actually the primary key of the data you want to delete, as it is actually used in mongodb

Answer (score 3):

It's a naming convention for private variables and methods used by some developers to indicate that they are private.

Also see:
[What is the underscore "_" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734399/what-is-the-underscore-in-javascript)