# Getter method does not need underscore to reference. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, get

I'm new to objects & methods and I'm creating a new key-value pair starting with an '_' (underscore) to see that it shouldn't be changed.

I just realized that I don't need to use the '_' when I create a getter method.

Why is that?

I am just learning about JavaScript and objects to be precise.

```
const team = {
  _players: [{
    firstName: 'Josh',
    lastName: 'Huan',
    age: 27
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Greg',
    lastName: 'Peterz',
    age: 33
  }
  ],
get players() {
  return this._players;
}
```

};

I thought that I just use the '_players' as the reference to the getter method, like 'get _players()...' but instead I don't need to use underscore.

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Underscores are just like any other character; they don't mean anything special.  What is your question?

Comment: I thought that when I create a getter method I need to reference with the name of the key (_players). But as you can see I am not using the same name just simply 'players' without the underscore. Question is: Why don't I need it there?

Comment: you are basically creating a brand new method, it doesn't have any idea that `_players` even exists. You could just as well do `get monkey() { return this._players }` if you wanted and it would work just the same.

Comment: Thank you Get Off My Lawn. All clear now ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't need to use the '_' when I create a getter method.

You don't "need" an underscore for anything. As you noted, the underscore marks properties which shouldn't be touched from outside, but [that's just a convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4484449/1048572). It's still a normal property name like any other.

What you *need* for your getter to work is just two different property names - one for the getter property and one for the data property that actually stores the value. You can use any two arbitrary property names for this.

Comment: Thank you very much Bergi! I've mistaken it for being a reference but now it's all clear. :)