# Difference between this.variable and this._variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning the Codecademy Advanced JavaScript course, I'm learning about classes.

In their code, I feel `this.variable` and `this._variable` have no different but they require to write `this.variable` even though 2 options return the same output.

Can you please explain the differences if you understand this?

These are some examples of code

```
class Dog {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name
  }
}
```

Is it different from:

```
class Dog {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}
```

Comment: They're named differently. One has an underscore in the name, the other doesn't. Without an example that's all we can say.

Comment: okay, let me add some code @evolutionbox

Comment: There is a convention that says variables that are prefixed with `_` are "private".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**

1.Names can contain letters, digits, underscores, and dollar signs.
2.Names must begin with a letter Names can also begin with $ and _
3.Names are case sensitive(y and Y are different variables)

**

Comment: i've added some code. you can check it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Define variables preceded by an underscore is just a convention to mark them as private, but javascript doesn't support encapsulation so this is only for helping the developer identify private variables.

In this post you have a similar question: [Is the underscore prefix for property and method names merely a convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484424/is-the-underscore-prefix-for-property-and-method-names-merely-a-convention)

Comment: Yes it does? https://medium.com/javascript-scene/encapsulation-in-javascript-26be60e325b4

Comment: Well, you can simulate it with clousures and scopes, but I meant encapsulation based on the variable definition (like in java you have private, protected or public)

Comment: We now do have some [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) in JS. I'm not sure if they're based on closures, though.

Comment: Didn't know about that, thanks @Teemu