# Difference between Javascript property with and without underscore

Tags: javascript

I saw the below [code](https://plnkr.co/edit/akniHp0z0nGGFi9b) at https://javascript.info/class

Its constructor is taking the `name` parameter and assigning it to `this.name`. Then in the getter named `name` it is returning `this._name`. Why does this [code](https://plnkr.co/edit/akniHp0z0nGGFi9b) work even when the constructor is not using `this._name` to set the value?

```
class User {

  constructor(name) {
    // invokes the setter
    this.name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(value) {
    if (value.length < 4) {
      alert("Name is too short.");
      return;
    }
    this._name = value;
  }

}

let user = new User("John");
alert(user.name); // John

user = new User(""); // Name is too short.
```

Comment: They are two different properties, because they have different names. In this code, the "_name" property is an ordinary property, while "name" is a getter/setter property.

Comment: The "_" itself means nothing; it is not special, just another character that can be used in an identifier.

Comment: JS variables names follow JS variable naming rules. That's it. Everrything matters: `name` is not `Name`, `_name` is not `name`, `$name` is not `name`, the end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the underscore prefix for property and method names merely a convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484424/is-the-underscore-prefix-for-property-and-method-names-merely-a-convention)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underscore is a normal character and doesn't have a special meaning in JavaScript. You could replace it with `p` for private or something else.

The property `this.name` has a getter and a setter.

`this.name = name;` in the constructor calls the setter. There is even a comment `// invokes the setter`.

The setter `set name(value)` sets `this._name = value;`.

Comment: does parameter value get passed to the setter automatically in the line this.name = name?

Comment: @vaichidrewar I don't understand your question. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Comment: I am still trying to understand details of how this.name = name is working. In this.name = name, is “this.name” referring to the setter method or name after the = is referring to the setter method or name after = is referring to parameter name?

Comment: @vaichidrewar `this.name` has a setter. When you assign a value with `=`, the setter is called. `this.name = value` calls the setter `name` with the argument `value`.

Answer (score 1):

The get and set keywords mean those funcs are invoked automagically, so when you create the new User and call `alert(user.name)`, you're accessing `_name` and never `name`. You could rename `_name` to `foo` or `_foo` and it would work the same way.

```
...
  get name() {
    return this.foo;
  }

  set name(value) {
    ...
    this.foo = value;
  }

}

let user = new User("John");
alert(user.name); // John (still works)
```