# Updating JavaScript class instance

Tags: javascript, class

When updating properties on a class instance, is this the best approach? I could use some clarification from a more experienced developer on this.

Here is my class:

```
class Cart {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.cartItems = [];
    this.cartSubtotal = 0;
    this.cartQuantity = 0;
  }

  getCartQuantity() {
    const qty =
      this.cartItems.reduce((quantity, item) => item.quantity + quantity, 0) ||
      0;
    return qty;
  }

  getCartSubTotal() {
    let subTotal = 0;
    this.cartItems.forEach((cartItem) => {
      const product = products.find(
        (product) => product.id === cartItem.productId
      );
      subTotal += cartItem.quantity * (product.price || 0);
    });
    return subTotal;
  }

  addItem(cartItem) {
    this.cartItems.push(cartItem);
  }
}
```

Here is my add cart item end point:

```
app.post('/addToCart/:cartId', (req, res) => {
  const { cartId } = req.params;
  const { id, quantity, detail } = req.body;
  const cart = getUserCart(cartId);

  const item = new CartItem(uuidv4(), id, quantity, detail);
  cart.addItem(item);
  cart.cartSubtotal = cart.getCartSubTotal();
  cart.cartQuantity = cart.getCartQuantity();

  res.json(cart);
});
```

Setting the values on the post call makes sense and it works but I feel like there is a more elegant way to do this.

```
cart.cartSubtotal = cart.getCartSubTotal();
cart.cartQuantity = cart.getCartQuantity();
```

Alternatively, would it make more sense to update the total and quantity from within the addToCart method instead of setting them in the post call?

```
addItem(cartItem) {
   this.cartItems.push(cartItem);
   this.cartSubtotal = this.getCartSubTotal();
   this.cartQuantity = this.getCartQuantity();
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Well if it'd make you feel better the "getCart ..." routines could be called "updateCart ..." and in addition to returning the updated value, could also set the instance property.

Comment: I suppose for something like this, maybe using `getters` would clean up the code a bit? you could lose the verb, using the get keyword, meaning you'd also no longer have to call it as a function since effectively, it becomes an attribute

Comment: `products` appears to be a global variable. Try to avoid that. The `price` should ideally be determined when the `CartItem` is constructed.

Comment: There's no need for `|| 0` after `reduce()`. It will return the initial value by default if the array is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it make more sense to update the total and quantity from within the `addToCart` method instead of setting them in the post call?

Yes, absolutely. This is the OOP best practice - you interact with an object only through method calls such as `addToCart()`, and the object itself is responsible for keeping its state up-to-date and consistent. You wouldn't want someone to update the `cartItems` but not the `cartSubtotal` or `cartQuantity` or only one of them. Also, if you were to introduce another cart property (e.g. average price), you would need to search for every call to `addToCart()` in the application and add another line to update the new property. That is precisely what modularisation is trying to avoid.

So you'd use

```
class Cart {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.items = [];
    this.#update();
  }
  #update() {
    this.quantity = this.items.reduce((quantity, item) => item.quantity + quantity, 0);
    this.subTotal = this.items.reduce((subTotal, item) => item.quantity * (item.getProduct().price ?? 0) + subTotal, 0);
  }
  addItem(cartItem) {
    this.items.push(cartItem);
    this.#update();
  }
}
```

An alternative would be to not store the `subTotal` and `quantity` in the cart at all (which means having to update it every time the items change), but to only compute it when the property is accessed - using a `get…` method or a getter property:

```
class Cart {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.items = [];
  }
  get quantity() {
    return this.items.reduce((quantity, item) => item.quantity + quantity, 0);
  }
  get subTotal() {
    return this.items.reduce((subTotal, item) => item.quantity * (item.getProduct().price ?? 0) + subTotal, 0);
  }
  addItem(cartItem) {
    this.items.push(cartItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the _ a personal preference or is that a naming convention for this type of class method? If _update is only called from within the class itself, should I make it private?

Comment: @reean917 Ah, yes, [it's a naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4484424/1048572), but indeed it would make sense here to just make it private